# Python switching back to local bin instead of using venv

Tags: python, python-venv

When using a venv i have previously activated, sooner or later after running several programs in the desired venv a few times, python will switch back to my local bin without me deactivating my venv.

Am I performing an incorrect task which makes python switch back to local?
Does this just occur randomly after a time period?

Running python 3.8 in vscode on macos.

When i activate the venv, i run:

```
user@Users-MacBook-Pro CurrentDirectory % source path_to_venv/bin/activate
```

And my venv is activated perfectly fine, proven so by using:

```
user@Users-MacBook-Pro CurrentDirectory % which python
```

and being returned with the path to my venv. The problem occurs after running some scripts a random amount of times, and the venv seems to deactivate itself. Proven by running the 'which python' command and being returned with:

'/usr/bin/python'

Comment: Are these commands run within the same terminal session?

Comment: Do any of the _"scripts"_ alter the environment variable `PATH` or `PYTHONHOME`?

Comment: I run all these commands usually from the same file (If not the same file, the same directory) within the VSCode terminal. I am regularly using the "os.path" call within my scripts for a multitude of reasons. Other than that, no environment variables are changed that i am aware of.

Comment: @navneethc , i lied to you in my previous answer. Whenever i wanted my terminal to go away from screen, i would kill the instance rather than clear it.

Comment: Well, there you have it. A virtual environment does not remain activated across sessions.